# Can I develop Android apps on a Sony Xperia Play?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm about to start Android development. After a bit of research it seems that the Sony Xperia Play is probably the most suitable Android-based gaming device.

Is it possible to develop for the Xperia Play like on any other Android-based phone, or does it require special licensing or other certification from Sony?

Answer (score 2):

All information needed to developer for Xperia Play is available as Sony Ericsson Developer World http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/technology/android/xperiaplay/overview?cc=gb&lc=en

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the Play will have the Android Market on it, so that means that normal Android apps can be downloaded and installed on it.  Although for development, you'll want to make sure that you can "sideload" (install apps by transferring the .apk file to the phone without using the Market) apps onto the phone so that you can test your apps on the real hardware.

Comment: You do not need to have sideloading enabled to develop on a phone. I have a Samsung Captivate, sideloading is completely disabled and I can develop and test on it.

Comment: Is it possible to do that on the Xperia Play? Because of course I would like to be able to use Eclipse with the NDK to develop, test and debug my apps right on the device. Anybody have experience with that?